# How to get the win32api Virtual Key Code of an entry value

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

Like the title suggest it's about the win32api Virtual key codes

see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

I need to convert a letter in an entry into it's virutal key code. If the entry value it's A we need to convert it as 0x41 if it's B it will be 0x42 if it's C 0x43 etc. And it can also work with Shift,Ctrl or Alt (that's not only with letters). My problem is that I don't know how to get their virtual key code based on the Key in the entry.

Right here for example you have an entry with value U we should obtain the virtual key code of U that is => 0x55

So when we click on the key, GetKeyState() of win32api will detect it (because it will be in the form 0x0...) and a click will be made with the help of pyautogui.

**It is absolutely necessary to convert the value of the input into virtual key code in order to get GetKeyState to work with**

**EDIT** :

```
if win32api.GetKeyState(win32api.VkKeyScan('alt')) < 0:
```

but it return =>

if win32api.GetKeyState(win32api.VkKeyScan('ctrl')) < 0:
TypeError: must be a unicode string of length 1

If it only work with one letter that's not that good... That's not a problem if numpad numbers or other are the same for keycode but the key that are not specific letters must work ...

Comment: Look at the Win32 `VkKeyScan/Ex()` and `MapVirtualKey/Ex()` functions

Comment: Any updates to the thread?

Comment: it's updated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pasting from [[SO]: How to convert values in Entry to win32api Virtual-Key Codes? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73810722/4788546) (for some reason you deleted that question).

If you want a *char* -> key code mapping you could:

- Create one manually (using the list from [[MS.Docs]: Virtual-Key Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes))
- Use [[MS.Docs]: VkKeyScanW function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-vkkeyscanw) (could also check [[MS.Docs]: MapVirtualKeyW function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapvirtualkeyw) out)

What's important to note:

- **More than one key could produce same virtual key code** (*e.g.* <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>NumPad 1</kbd>)
- There are no combined key codes, so for one character (when <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> are also pressed) there will be more than 1

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

import win32api as wapi
import win32con as wcon


def vks(c):
    ret = []
    res = wapi.VkKeyScan(c)
    ss = (res >> 8) & 0xFF
    if ss & 0x01:
        ret.append(wcon.VK_SHIFT)
    if ss & 0x02:
        ret.append(wcon.VK_CONTROL)
    if ss & 0x04:
        ret.append(wcon.VK_MENU)
    ret.append(res & 0xFF)
    return tuple(ret)


def main(*argv):
    print("Sample key values:")
    print(["0x{:02X} ({:d})".format(e, e) for e in (wcon.VK_SHIFT, wcon.VK_CONTROL, wcon.VK_MENU, ord("y"), ord("Y"))])
    print("\nScan cdess:")
    for c in (
        "y",
        "Y",
        "\x79",
        "\x59",
        "\x19",
    ):
        print(vks(c))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073840049]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Sample key values:
> ['0x10 (16)', '0x11 (17)', '0x12 (18)', '0x79 (121)', '0x59 (89)']
>
> Scan cdess:
> (89,)
> (16, 89)
> (89,)
> (16, 89)
> (17, 89)
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I had deleted my old topic because not enough visibility so now i'm back to this one. I will put what I did in edit and indeed the VirtualKeyScan can not take Ctrl, Alt or Shift because more than 1, that's a problem ... I will edit my first message

Comment: How I can it accept more than one ? (With VirtualKeyScan)

Comment: Then you can hardcode the table instead of `VirtualKeyScan`.

Comment: What do you mean by hardcode the table ?

Comment: As the answer said, create one manually according to [\[MS.Docs\]: Virtual-Key Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes).